# Why is this Tailwindcss `text-opacity-n` utility class not working on this element?

Tags: tailwind-css

Just as specified in the TailwindCSS docs I'm directly applying opacity to the same element that has its colour directly applied:

```
<th class="border border-slate-300 font-display text-green-800 text-opacity-20 text-xl py-2 px-4">Departure Date & Time</th>
```

yet the opacity value is not taking effect. It just keeps being overridden by the `--tw-text-opacity` variable, as seen below from the styles tab in inspector:

```
.text-green-800 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(22 101 52/var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
```

What am i misunderstanding here and how can i get this to work?

Comment: It seems to work for me: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Rrj91jbN3P

Comment: Strange this case, I just can't seem to get it to apply. The element has a background, is in a table, none of which should effect it, the layout template doesn't have anything that should be effecting it, there's no custom styles that should effect it. Other Tailwindcss utlity classes are working. I put an isolated <p> element on the page and it won't work there either. Likely/surely something daft that I'm doing but I just can't see what .

Comment: I know Tailwind classes like to be in a specific order. Not sure if that's just for consistency and formatting purposes or if it actually changes the behavior, but try the following. It is the same thing you have, but they are in the Tailwind "preferred order":  `<th class="font-display border border-slate-300 px-4 py-2 text-xl text-green-800 text-opacity-20">Departure Date & Time</th>`

Comment: Thanks for the further suggestion. The issue was, i think, something to do with config of Tailwind. I just ran into another issue whilst trying to integrate DaisyUI via npm install, and it not working at all, playing with import statements, only being able to get DaisyUI to work via CDN, then removing and trying again with the npm installation then managing somehow to get DaisyUI to work, and at the same time then these TailwindCSS opacity classes start to work. I'm unsure exactly what happened, I'd guess that it's been something to do with compilation and caching, but then I'm in devleopment.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works anyway, but try to add a 'p' element and add those text classes here:

```
<th class="border border-slate-300 font-display py-2 px-4">
<p class="text-green-800 text-opacity-20 text-xl">Departure Date & Time</p>
</th>
```

if this not solve the problem try to import tailwind with cdn instead of downloading it (maybe the problem is related to the local version)

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Framar. The issue has been something to do with Tailwind config, though I'm unable to write up an exact answer because I was unable to exactly diagnose it. See my comment to @Icemanind above which explains where i got to. Something to do with local compilation i think.